# How to get highlighted text from my NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

It must be certainly easy but I haven't found anything in the doc.
The behavior I need is exactly as when you right-click any portion of text and then you can do some action with it.
For the moment I have a my own custom NSTextField class which re-implment 'mouseDown' action. This part works ! I thought I could get the selected portion of text of my nstextfield thanks to 'theEvent' but apparently it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually think you can do this with NSTextField. I think you have to use an NSTextView instead and then make use of the `-selectedRanges` method.

EDIT: I should have said, you can't do this *directly* (i.e., there's no NSTextField method for doing this). I think rather, you have to use the field editor (which is itself an NSTextView) associated with the window in order to do this. [Here's the apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html) for using the field editor.

Comment: Yes, i thought about that ... but I would prefer stay with my NSTextField... But once again a lot of app are able to do that in a NSTextField... So i was wondering ...

Comment: cool. i edited my above answer to be (hopefully) more helpful.

Comment: It seems pretty interesting ! Thanks !

Comment: Broken link; updated one = https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW29

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *selectedText = ((NSTextFieldCell*)textField.selectedCell).stringValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Sean 's answer, I use the following solution to get/change the selected text of an NSTextField:

```
- (BOOL) replaceSelectionOfField:(NSTextField *)textField withString:(NSString *)replacement {
    NSText * editor = [self.view.window fieldEditor:NO forObject:textField];
    if (editor) {
        NSRange rng = editor.selectedRange;
        if (rng.location != NSNotFound) {
            [editor replaceCharactersInRange:rng withString:replacement];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

If this function returns `NO`, there is either no field editor (the text field may not have focus) or no selection.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTextField` internally uses `NSTextView`, so we can just find that text view, then use its public API to get the selection range, then calculate the selected text. (Tested on macOS 13.5.2)

```
extension NSTextField {
    
    func kjy_selectedText() -> String {
        guard let range = kjy_selectedRange(), range.length > 0 else { return "" }
        return (stringValue as NSString).substring(with: range)
    }
    
    func kjy_selectedRange() -> NSRange? {
        for subview in subviews {
            for subSubview in subview.subviews {
                if let textView = subSubview as? NSTextView,
                   let range = textView.selectedRanges.first?.rangeValue,
                   range.location != NSNotFound
                {
                    return range
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

View hierarchy:

[image: View hierarchy]